# Partial unescape html string

Tags: html, go

I have webapp. Go html template will escape all unsafe tag. Is there way to selectively escape a string? For instance, Google.com will highlight your search query and wrap it with `<em>` tag while all other html & javascript gets escaped. [I have this](https://play.golang.org/p/Y5cvDCl4ad):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
)

func main() {
    s := "<i>This should be escaped</i><strong>This should be in bold</strong>."
    h := template.HTMLEscaper(s)
    fmt.Println(h)
}
```

Right now everything gets escaped. I am aware you can do a template function with template.HTML(mystring) but how do I do that for part of a string?

thx!

EDIT:
I would like the final string to be:

```
&lt;i&gt;This should be escaped&lt;/i&gt;<strong>This should be in bold</strong>.
```

To be clear, I have tried creating a template function to highlight matches...the html I add gets escaped in the actual template ;(

Comment: Split the string into parts and handle the parts differently.

Comment: @kristen : It is helpful if you add some sample inputs and desired outputs to your Question

Comment: How do you intend to differentiate what you want escaped, and what you don't?

Comment: As @Volker states you split the string into parts & handle the parts differently....I just don't know how to handle each part...

Comment: @Volker: can you be more specific?

Comment: Well, you split `s` at the appropriate location, maybe my finding a "split index" and doing `e, u := s[:i], s[i+1:]` and wrap `s` in `template.HTML` before passing both `e` and `s` to a template for execution (which will encode `e` and keep `s`).

Comment: I think it's a bit more involved than that. You'd have to ensure that e only contains text characters and no html or other unsafe characters.